# Unable to correctly pull or display from localStorage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, local-storage

As per question, I am unable to retrieve or display items that I have saved to localStorage. I believe I may have my variables set wrong or not applying the correct logic. I know I have to add a `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(storedName)) || []`, but I'm not sure where it goes exactly and not sure how to then just set the `textInput.val` to the localStorage items. Every time I try, all the rows (timeBlock) go missing from the page.

```
// DOM elements pulling from HTML
var currentDay = $("#currentDay");
var schedule = $('.container');

// Moment.js variables
var now = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
var currentHour = moment().hour();

// Global variables
var workDay = 9;

// --------------------------------------------------->
// START OF PROGRAM
// --------------------------------------------------->

// Setting Current Day to top of the calendar
$(currentDay.text(now));
  
// Adding Rows dynamically using the DOM
for (var i = 0; i < workDay; i++) {

  // Setting time blocks main divs
  var timeBlock = $("<div>").addClass("row time-row");
  timeBlock.attr("id", i + 1);

  // Setting hour column
  var hourCol = $("<div>").addClass("hour col-1");
  hourCol.text(moment().hour(i + workDay).format("hA"));

  // Setting save column
  var saveCol = $("<button>").addClass("saveBtn col-1 fas fa-save");
  saveCol.attr("data-index", i);

  // Setting text input area for timeblocks
  var textInput = $("<textarea>").addClass("task time-block future");

  /* Appending all columns to timeBlock divs and then
  appending timeBlock div to main Schedule container */
  timeBlock.append(hourCol);
  timeBlock.append(textInput);
  timeBlock.append(saveCol);
  schedule.append(timeBlock);

  // Setting textArea color depending on time as defined by currentHour variable
  if (currentHour === (i + workDay)) {
    textInput.attr("class", "task col-10 present");
  }
  else if (currentHour > (i + workDay)){
    textInput.attr("class", "task col-10 past");
  };
};

// Saving work schedule tasks to localStorage()
$('.saveBtn').on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var workHour = $(this).parent().attr("id");
  var setTask = $(this).siblings(".task").val();
  localStorage.setItem(workHour, setTask);
});

// --------------------------------------------------->
//  END OF PROGRAM
// --------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: Perhaps I am missing it but I see nothing here in your code attempt related to localStorage ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: The `getItem` would typically go where need to populate the previous values when loading, if any. I'm thinking possibly before the loop to process `workDay`, so that the stored `workHour` info is available where need in the loop? ... but I'm not 100% sure, that would be your call.

Comment: 1. Enclose all jQuery code in `$(function() {` ... `});` to act on DOM ready. 2. Your timeBlock id is just a number, which is not specific enough for the local storage item name because the local storage is used by all pages in the current domain. So do something like this: `var name = 'timeBlock-' + $(this).parent().attr("id"); `, and use that name in `localStorage.setItem()`. 3. You can inspect the local storage in the dev tools under Application. 4. To read the local storage, build and use the same name: `var val = localStorage.getItem() || '';`. 5. Set the textarea value with `.val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enclose all jQuery code in `$(function() {` ... `});` to make sure the DOM is ready.
2. Your timeBlock id is just a number, which is not specific enough for the local storage item name because the local storage is used by all pages in the current domain. So do something like this: `var name = 'timeBlock-' + $(this).parent().attr("id");` , and use that name in `localStorage.setItem()`.
3. You can inspect the local storage in the developer tools under Application.
4. To read the local storage, build and use the same name: `var val = localStorage.getItem(name) || '';`.
5. Set the textarea value with `.val()`

Your code fixed, but untested:

```
$(function() {
  // DOM elements pulling from HTML
  var currentDay = $("#currentDay");
  var schedule = $('.container');
  
  // Moment.js variables
  var now = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY");
  var currentHour = moment().hour();
  
  // Global variables
  var workDay = 9;
  
  // --------------------------------------------------->
  // START OF PROGRAM
  // --------------------------------------------------->
  
  // Setting Current Day to top of the calendar
  $(currentDay.text(now));
    
  // Adding Rows dynamically using the DOM
  for (var i = 0; i < workDay; i++) {
  
    // Setting time blocks main divs
    var timeBlock = $("<div>").addClass("row time-row");
    timeBlock.attr("id", i + 1);
  
    // Setting hour column
    var hourCol = $("<div>").addClass("hour col-1");
    hourCol.text(moment().hour(i + workDay).format("hA"));
  
    // Setting save column
    var saveCol = $("<button>").addClass("saveBtn col-1 fas fa-save");
    saveCol.attr("data-index", i);
  
    // Setting text input area for timeblocks
    var textInput = $("<textarea>").addClass("task time-block future");
    var name = 'timeBlock-' + (i + 1);
    var val = localStorage.getItem(name) || '';
    textInput.val(val);

    /* Appending all columns to timeBlock divs and then
    appending timeBlock div to main Schedule container */
    timeBlock.append(hourCol);
    timeBlock.append(textInput);
    timeBlock.append(saveCol);
    schedule.append(timeBlock);
  
    // Setting textArea color depending on time as defined by currentHour variable
    if (currentHour === (i + workDay)) {
      textInput.attr("class", "task col-10 present");
    }
    else if (currentHour > (i + workDay)){
      textInput.attr("class", "task col-10 past");
    };
  };

  // Saving work schedule tasks to localStorage()
  $('.saveBtn').on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = 'timeBlock-' + $(this).parent().attr("id");
    var val = $(this).siblings(".task").val();
    localStorage.setItem(name, val);
  });
});
```